# Django : Add JSON POST data into the database

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an API for a butcher.
With this API and the website that I will build by the next, the client will be able to make his order remotly.
Here is my probleme.
With the order form, the client send me JSON data like here :

```
{
    "user": 8,
    "orderDay": "2020-06-24",
    "deliveryDay": "2020-06-30",
    "deliveryAddress": "Place des Fêtes",
    "comment": "",
    "orderDetail": 
    [
        {
            "product": 2,
            "byProduct": 2,
            "quantity": 43
        },
        {
            "product": 3,
            "byProduct": 3,
            "quantity": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

These data must be saved in the database.
These are the models that I use : **models.py**

```
class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(memberArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    orderDay = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deliveryDay = models.DateField()
    deliveryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class orderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    byProduct = models.ForeignKey(byProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prix_uni = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    prix_kg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    dispo = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    redu = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class byProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I make a serializer file like this **serializer.py**

```
class orderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset = order.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = orderDetail
        fields = '__all__'

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orderDetail = orderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ['user', 'comment', 'deliveryAddress', 'deliveryDay', 'orderDetail']

    def create(self, validated_data):
            order_detail_data = validated_data.pop('orderDetail')
            new_order = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
            new_order.save()
            for product in order_detail_data:
                order_detail = orderDetail.objects.create(order=new_order, **product)
                new_order.orderDetail.add(order_detail.id)
            
            return new_order
```

And this is my view : **views.py**:

```
#Make an order
@api_view(['POST'])
def order(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "Your order went well"
            return Response(data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

When I try to run my code, it tells me that the order data is missing :

```
{
    "orderDetail": [
        {
            "order": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        },
        {
            "order": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to add this because the order_id that I need is created at the same time that the orderDetail.
Thank's by advance for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should make `order` field `readonly` in `orderDetailSerializer`:

```
class orderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = orderDetail
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('order',)
```

Comment: When I make this field `read_only` I get this error : `AssertionError: Relational fields should not provide a `queryset` argument, when setting read_only=`True`.`

Comment: you da real mvp :D